# Rails parent child form example preventing mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

I use rails 3.2 and I want to prevent mass-assignment. I have parent-child relationship.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :children
    attr_accessible :name
end
class Child < ActiveRecord:Base
    belongs_to :parent
    attr_accessible :title
end
```

In my routes.rb child resource is not nested within parent resource. Now I have a link to create a new child with `new_child_path(@parent.id)`. This directs me to `localhost:3000/child/new?parent_id=1` and I end up in `new` action:

```
def new
    @child = Child.new
    @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
    @child.parent = @parent
end
```

My question is: how to write my `_form.html.erb` for a child entity? I cannot use `f.hidden_field` for `parent_id` because in my create action it would break up because of mass-assignment. On the other hand I need to pass `parent_id` to know my parent when I save child. I haven't found a good working example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on Rails' nested resources.

Some links:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

-- EDIT 1 --

Based on your comment of not having more than one level of nesting, you could also have the following route configuration:

```
resources :grandparents do
    resources :parents
end

resources :parents do
    resources :children
end
```

This way, you can still have the parent child relationship, without the overheads of multiple levels of nesting. You could also namespace your controllers to keep things clean, eg:

```
resources :grandparents do
    resources :parents, :controller => "grandparent/parent"
end

resources :parents do
    resources :children
end
```

Comment: I did read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources but I've followed a rule: Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep, so I dropped my nested resources.

Comment: This solves an issue of having parent_id in my URL while creating a book. Too bad this routes practice is not widely popular. Thank you.